# Nested routes don't work?

Tags: react-router

Hi lovely stackoverflowers, I am using react@0.14.5 and react-router@1.0.3(installed with @latest).

The example is not working for me (below). When I navigate to http://mysite/about or click on the About link, the home page will always be shown.

[image: example code]

Before click

[image]

After click

[image]

I fixed this by removing the nested structure (code below), and now it works as expected.

[image]

Am I using this package wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when rendering child (nested) routes, you need to have the this.props.children in your parent route for it to render the child route.

For ex put this into the render method on your App:

`<div>
{this.props.children}
</div>`

Comment: Ah, quite different from last time I use it. Thank you. I feel too old for breaking changes.